# Grouping array by array values

Tags: arrays, swift

I have many arrays, and I want to group that array by array values. how to make script function to grouping array for that?

I have arrays like below

```
["TODAY","TODAY","MONDAY","MONDAY","TUESDAY","TUESDAY","SUNDAY"]
["Angela","Hane","Amel","JOHN","Joseph","Dickinson","RICK"]
["DEV","PRO","ADMIN","PRO","ADMIN","DEV","PRO"]
```

I want to group become a new array

```
[TODAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,SUNDAY]
//depends by days
[
    [//today
        [Angela,Hane]
        [DEV,PRO]

    ],

    [//monday
        [Amel,JOHN]
        [ADMIN,PRO]
    ],

    [//tuesday
        [Joseph,Dickinson]
        [ADMIN,DEV]
    ]
    [//sunday
        [RICK]
        [PRO]
    ]
]
```

swift

```
let days = [TODAY,TODAY,MONDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,TUESDAY,SUNDAY]
let arr1 = [Angela,Hane,Amel,JOHN,Joseph,Dickinson,RICK]
let arr2 = [DEV,PRO,ADMIN,PRO,ADMIN,DEV,PRO]



//depends on days

let items = [
    [//today
        [Angela,Hane]
        [DEV,PRO]

    ],

    [//monday
        [Amel,JOHN]
        [ADMIN,PRO]
    ],

    [//tuesday
        [Joseph,Dickinson]
        [ADMIN,DEV]
    ]
    [//sunday
        [RICK]
        [PRO]
    ]
]
```

I need this array grouping to show in table view using header.. please help me to create a script to generate this.

Thank you for any help.

I appreciated it.

Comment: How did you get the data in the arrays like that in the first place?

Comment: You should at least try to solve it first. It's rude to just ask for the entire solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your design. Rather than using multiple arrays use a struct

```
struct Person {
    let name, weekday, type : String
}

let items = [Person(name: "Angela", weekday: "TODAY", type: "DEV"),
             Person(name: "Hane", weekday: "TODAY", type: "PRO"),
             Person(name: "Amel", weekday: "MONDAY", type: "ADMIN"),
             Person(name: "JOHN", weekday: "MONDAY", type: "PRO"),
             Person(name: "Joseph", weekday: "TUESDAY", type: "ADMIN"),
             Person(name: "Dickinson", weekday: "TUESDAY", type: "DEV"),
             Person(name: "RICK", weekday: "SUNDAY", type: "PRO")]
```

Then you can group them pretty easy

```
let groupedItems = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: {$0.weekday})
```

To display the items get the keys (you might add a logic to sort them)

```
let keys = Array(groupedItems.keys)
```

and get the corresponding value by key

```
let section = keys[indexPath.section]
let people = groupedItems[section]!
let row = people[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: thankyou.. im new .. how to populate cellForRowAt using dictionary grouping you gave ?

Comment: Make `keys` and `groupedItems` properties of the class and use the last code snippet. `row` contains one person and you can show the name with `cell.textLabel?.text = row.name`

Comment: depends on your example sir,, how to sort the dictionary grouping.. if i want the weekday showup for the first row.. ? Thankyou anyway @vadian

Comment: Obviously the weekdays cannot be sorted. You need a logic to map the names to sortable indices.

Comment: if i add the struct called "No" (1,2,3,4,5,6,7).. how can i sort it programmatically.. dictionary.sorted({$0.No}).. how do i implement it ?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can solve the issue with your current code using 3 separate `arrays`.

First of all, you can use **`zip(_:_:)`** to get a combined `array` from all the 3 `arrays`.

```
let days = ["TODAY","TODAY","MONDAY","MONDAY","TUESDAY","TUESDAY","SUNDAY"]
let arr1 = ["Angela","Hane","Amel","JOHN","Joseph","Dickinson","RICK"]
let arr2 = ["DEV","PRO","ADMIN","PRO","ADMIN","DEV","PRO"]

let arr = Array(zip(days, zip(arr1, arr2)))
```

Now, group the `arr` based on the `day` using,

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: {$0.0})
```

Further, you can use `grouped` to fetch data based on `days` like,

```
let values = grouped[days[indexPath.row]]
```

**Note:** Instead of making 3 separate `arrays`, its better you create a `struct/class` type and use that to represent all your data.